# Webcam device not detected, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: webcam

I just did an update to ubuntu and not my webcam is not being detected.
Weird part is that is being detected by lsusb.

I'm using an inspiron 15 series and don't have the option of turning the webcam on and off.

```
lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:671e Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD

lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
```

I really appreciate any input.